# Storing arrays index values C++

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I currently have a float array declared and intialised with a range of values e.g. 3.2, 4.4,9.8 . A while loop adds the highest value element of the array into a variaible highestVal. This works as it should and the highest element in the array is outputed. I am trying to find a way to store the index of the highest element i.e if the value is 3.4, I also want to store the index of that value in the array. Can anyone point me towards what the basic method would be to store this index value.

```
int const MAXVALUES = 10;
int counter = 0;
float floatPointNumber[MAXVALUES] = { 1.3, 9.2, 2.2, 4.4, 2.5, 2.7, 9.2, 7.9, 9.2, 9.6 };
int index = -1;
float highestArrayVal = 0;

while (counter < MAXVALUES)
{
    cout << floatPointNumber[counter] << endl;

    while (floatPointNumber[counter]>highestArrayVal)
    {
        highestArrayVal = floatPointNumber[counter];

        //index = floatPointNumber[counter];
        break;
    }
    counter = counter + 1;
}

cout << "Highest Array Value " << highestArrayVal << endl;
cout << "Index of this element " << index << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: Show your code and we'll add that one line into your loop.  :)

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3057164 click the [edit] link.

Comment: Do you know which other variable happens to contain this index when `floatPointNumber[counter]` is the highest number?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple, but you'll get back an iterator pointing to the element rather than an actual index.

```
const auto it = max_element(begin(floatingPointNumber), end(floatingPointNumber));
```

This iterator is essentially a pointer. So for example you can find the value of the largest element like this:

```
const auto highestArrayVal = *it;
```

Since `it` is a pointer you may no longer need an the exact index, but if you still do, you can do the following:

```
const auto index = distance(begin(floatingPointNumber), it);
```